# Draw Graph to a Second Degree Function C# Windows Form

Tags: c#

I have a Second Degree Function, what will be the best way to draw a graph to it using Windows Form?

Comment: An equation don't have a graph, a function does...

Comment: i solved the ecuation...i`m asking of of a way to draw the graph what shoulb i use

Comment: Drawing a graph of f(x,y)=c is simply by doing f(x,y)<c to get boolean out from any equation for each point in (x,y) space. bool b(int x, int y) { return f(x,y)<c; }

Answer (score 2):

```
1) Set range of arguments (for example -20<x<20)
2) compute values for this points (with accuracy 0.5)
3) Scale your graph to display resolution
4) Connect points by lines
```